# Unexpected response code 200

Tags: android, api, android-volley

> 12-02 12:26:58.984 4028-4069/com.example.sainathpawar.volleyimage
>   E/Volley: **[162] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response
>   code 200** for http://lorempixel.com/600/400/city/ 12-02 12:26:58.985
>   4028-4028/com.example.sainathpawar.volleyimage I/Error: Error 12-02
>   12:27:00.262 4028-4068/com.example.sainathpawar.volleyimage E/Volley:
>   [161] **BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 200**
>   for http://lorempixel.com/600/400/city/ 12-02 12:27:00.264
>   4028-4028/com.example.sainathpawar.volleyimage I/Error: Error

Getting above error what does this error mean?I am trying to fetch images from API "http://lorempixel.com/600/400/city/" is it related to permission?

Below is my code for which I am getting an error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String myURL = "http://lorempixel.com/600/400/city/";

        Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(myURL,
                        new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {

                            }
                        }, 0, 0, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i("Error","Error");
                    }
                });
                MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequest(imageRequest);
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

Comment: Can u elaborate the situation where you are getting this result

Comment: I have created a singleton class and I have called that singleton class into my main Activity and passed a request to it

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by changing the domain to the true IP address:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://182.92.79.215:3007');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ?>
```

add this in your php code, maybe adding a piece of this code can help you to solve this problem... :)

Comment: Do you also have a reason why that would help?